# Are weakeventmessagebroker and messagebroker Ninject extensions deprecated?

Tags: ninject, ninject-extensions

I'm trying to find the most up-to-date Ninject extension for development of event brokers / message brokers.

I could locate at least 3: [messagebroker](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.messagebroker), [weakeventmessagebroker](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.weakeventmessagebroker) and [bbveventbroker](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.bbveventbroker).

messagebroker's documentation [states](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.messagebroker/wiki):

```
This extension isn’t obsolete and replaced by ninject.extensions.bbveventbroker
```

Also, weakeventmessagebroker's documentation [reads](http://www.ninject.org/extensions.html):

```
Originally based on Ninject.Extensions.MessageBroker.
```

and [also](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.weakeventmessagebroker/wiki):

```
This extension isn’t obsolete and replaced by ninject.extensions.bbveventbroker
```

I wonder if this documentation is correct and those extensions are not obsolete, or if the documentation is just mistyped and it meant to say "This extension **is** obsolete..."

So the question is: have weakeventmessagebroker and messagebroker been deprecated in favor of bbveventbroker? What is the most current event broker extension for Ninject?

Comment: Links please so people can quickly fix them. Most of them are typos and your guess is correct

Comment: I updated my question with links to the extensions and the relevant documentation pages. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they are obsolete. One message broker is enough and ninject.extensions.bbveventbroker is the most flexible/feature rich one.

Thanks for pointing out the incorrect documentation. I just fixed it.